# OOM in tez/hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, out-of-memory, tez

[After a few answers and comments I asked a new question based on the knowledge gained here: [Out of memory in Hive/tez with LATERAL VIEW json_tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462896/out-of-memory-in-hive-tez-with-lateral-view-json-tuple) ]

One of my query consistently fails with the error:

```
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1516602562532_3606_2_03, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1516602562532_3606_2_03_000001, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Container container_e113_1516602562532_3606_01_000008 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=255. Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e113_1516602562532_3606_01_000008
Exit code: 255
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255
]], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
```

The keyword here seems to be `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I looked around but none of what I thought I understood from Tez helps me:

- ​yarn-site/yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is maxed up => I use all the memory I can
- yarn-site/yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb: same as yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
- yarn-site/yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 1024
- hive-site/hive.tez.container.size = 4096 (multiple of yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb)

​My query has 4 mappers, 3 go very fast, the 4th dies everytime. Here is the Tez graphical view of the query:

[image: tez graphical view]

From this image:

- table contact has 150M rows, 283GB of ORC compressed data (there is one large json field, LATERAL VIEW'ed)
- table m has 1M rows, 20MB of ORC compressed data
- table c has 2k rows, < 1MB ORC compressed
- table e has 800k rows, 7GB of ORC compressed
- e is LEFT JOIN'ed with all the other tables

e and contact are partitioned and only one partition in selected in the WHERE clause.

I thus tried to increase the number of maps:

- tez.grouping.max-size: 650MB by default, even if I lower it to -
  tez.grouping.min-size​ (16MB) it makes no difference
- tez.grouping.split-count even increased to 1000 does not make a difference
- tez.grouping.split-wave 1.7 by default, even increased to 5 makes no difference

If it's relevant, here are some other memory settings:

- mapred-site/mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 1024 (Min container size)
- mapred-site/mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 2048 (2 * min container size)
- mapred-site/mapreduce.map.java.opts = 819 (0.8 * min container size)
- mapred-site/mapreduce.reduce.java.opts = 1638 (0.8 * mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb)
- mapred-site/yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb = 2048 (2 * min container size)
- mapred-site/yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts = 1638 (0.8 * yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb)
- mapred-site/mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb = 409 (0.4 * min container size)

My understanding was that tez can split the work in many loads, thus taking long but eventually completing. ​Am I wrong, or is there a way I have not found?

context: hdp2.6, 8 datanodes with 32GB Ram, query using a chunky lateral view based on json run via beeline.

Comment: What if you convert the table to use ORC format with Snappy compression?

Comment: @cricket_007 this is already how my tables are stored.

Comment: Okay... Nothing is stopping you from converting to another format using Hive

Answer (score 1):

The issue is clearly due to SKEWED data. I would recommand that you add DISTRIBUTE BY COL to you select query from source so that the reducer has evenly distributed data. In the below example COL3 is more evenly distributed data like ID column
Example

```
ORIGINAL QUERY : insert overwrite table X AS SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 from Y
NEW QUERY      : insert overwrite table X AS SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 from Y distribute by COL3
```

Comment: I will try that asap but quick question: could you explain the 'clearly'? It looks obvious to you that data is skewed, but how do you guess?

Comment: Just a guess: You state: "My query has 4 mappers, 3 go very fast, the 4th dies everytime.". This is already a statement for skewed (unevenly distributed) data.

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach thanks - I added a graphical view of my query to the question. As you can see, the map failing is a combination of other maps (for lack of better wording). Not sure if skewness can be seen that way? My first try with `distribute by` yield the same issue.

Comment: I have see no change after adding `distribute by`.

Comment: Hi @Guillaume, From the diagram I understand that the query is being translated as a MAPJOIN. You can try to set "set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask = false;", if you can try this we can determine that the issue is because you are trying to MAPJOIN a very large dataset.

Comment: @BalaramRaju thanks, I just tried it but no difference unfortunately. I added more info about the table sizes in the question if relevant and am experimenting with other join settings.

Comment: @BalaramRaju After your comments I understand much more of my problem. It is not yet solved but I asked another more precise question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462896/out-of-memory-in-hive-tez-with-lateral-view-json-tuple

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and increasing all the memory parameter didnt help.

Then I switched to MR and got the below error.

```
Failed with exception Number of dynamic partitions created is 2795, which is more than 1000.
```

After setting the higher value I returned back to tez, and the problem was solved.